# One Form/Submit Two Actions

Tags: php, forms, authentication, submit, action

I have a bit of a problem with my website. I have phpbb integrated into my website and a login form on the homepage. This form needs to execute two different actions. It first needs to run the ucp.php (to log into phpbb) and also the login.php (to hide the form and add control panel on home screen). They both work by themselves, I just need a way to have them together when a user logs in. i have researched this for a while and can't find a solution. Thanks in advances, Josh

I need to combine this

```
<form action="./forums/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with this

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Can you not just include `login.php` at the end of `ucp.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a serious design issue in your code if you have to "merge" stuff like that, but in any case:

Just create a new file ie. `post_handler.php` and toss this code in it:

```
<?php
include('forums/upc.php');
include('login.php');
?>
```

Place it in the same directory as login.php.

Then adjust your form to point to `post_handler.php?mode=login`.

Ofcourse merging files like that could result in crazy unexpected results..

Another option, though more complex, would be to use the `login.php` as your action and do a curl request to `forums/ucp.php` inside it. (search for Curl on php.net documentation)

Unfortunately I can not give more suggestions, because what you are trying to do is probably more complex then something that can easily be answered here.

Comment: what would I put into the post handler? I understand how it works, I just don't know what to put in it.

Comment: Oh I didnt set my code block correctly.. I'll edit my post :)

Comment: Keep in mind though that how things will work is totally dependant on the content of the 2 included files. Personally i think you should switch them around (so login.php first and then forums/upc.php) because you probably have more control over login.php, so less chance of conflicts int he files.

Comment: ok cool, thanks for all your help. I ended up just redesigning my code. Like you said, it was poorly designed. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try trick with ajax. Here is an example that should work with jquery:
Im not sure if preventDefaut() wont make us a problem here and we still be allowed to use .submit() on it. If it wont work. Try to put whole thing into function, remove preventDefault and bind this function into submit button.

```
<form id="form_id" action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
User name: <inputy type="text" id="username" name="username" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      //we prevent normal form submit
      $('#form_id').preventDefault();
      var data = {} ;
          //here u build data u want send by taking it from form field by field
      //example
      data['username'] = $('#username');

          //and you send this data via ajax to your upc script
          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/forums/ucp.php?mode=login',
        data: data,
                //in case of succes we send form normal way
        success: function( xhr ) { $('#form_id').submit(); },
        dataType: String
        });

    });

<script>
```